# Javascript regular expression selecting multiple

Tags: javascript, regex

my problem is selected expressions cant use more than one but i need it

here i prepare a example of what i want

```js
var regexp = /(^| )([a-z]{1})( |$)/gim;

var string = "h ello e x a mple";

var choosen = string.match(regexp);

for(var i = 0; i < choosen.length; i++){
    console.log(choosen[i]);
}
```

you can see this only chooses `"h ", " e ", " a "`

but i want to choose `"h", "e", "x", "a"` without any `" "`

i know i can do it without regexp but this is really important for me

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any actual question here.  On the face of it you're asking for this: `/-([a-z])-/ig`.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you may simply try matching all groups consisting of non separator characters:

```js
var input = "h ello e x ample";
var matches = [];
var regexp = /\b[^\s]\b/g;
match = regexp.exec(input);
while (match != null) {
    matches.push(match[0]);
    match = regexp.exec(input);
}

console.log(matches);
```

The regex pattern `\b[^\s]\b` seeks to match any single non whitespace character which is also bounded on both sides by word boundaries.  In this case, it translates to matching the single letters (though it could also match other things, depending on a different input).